# After change class function doesn't work

Tags: python, django

After cut function about comments from ContentDetailView to IndexView I can't run my server and it doesn't work.

```
class IndexView(AllAdsViewMixin, ListView):
model = UserContent
template_name = 'user_content/list.html'
context_object_name = 'usercontent'

def get_queryset(self):
    """Return the last all five published contents"""
    return UserContent.objects.filter(state='1').order_by('-published')[:5]

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    content_type = self.object.get_content_type
    initial_data = {
        'content_type': content_type,
        'object_id': self.object.id,
    }

    comment_form = CommentForm(initial=initial_data)
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(
        content_type=content_type,
        object_id=self.object.id
    )

    context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['comments'] = comments
    context['comment_form'] = comment_form

    return context

def post(self, request, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    content_type = self.object.get_content_type
    comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST)

    if comment_form.is_valid():
        content_data = comment_form.cleaned_data.get('content')
        parent_obj = None
    try:
        parent_id = int(request.POST.get('parent_id'))
    except:
        parent_id = None

    if parent_id:
        parent_qs = Comment.objects.filter(parent__id=parent_id)
        if parent_qs.exists() and parent_qs.count() == 1:
            parent_obj = parent_qs.first()

    new_comment, created = Comment.objects.get_or_create(
        user=request.user,
        content_type=content_type,
        object_id=self.object.id,
        content=content_data,
        parent=parent_obj
    )

    return self.get(request, **kwargs)
```

Error:

```
'IndexView' object has no attribute 'object'
```

Can someone help me?

When function was in class ContentDetailView it works. ContentDetailView class has the same model, template_name and context_object_name.

Comment: First, "it doesn't work" isn't a helpful description, please see [ask]. Now what would be the "object" of a `ListView`? What was the object when it was a `DetailView`?

Comment: Functions def get_context_data and def_post was in ContentDetailView class. Now I need to throw that functions to the IndexView class. Finally it doesn't work. I have that error when I pasted context_object_name = 'object' and I'm beginner and I don't know what can I do. Sorry for my lack of competence and bad English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ContentDetailView` class was inherited from `DetailView`, but your `IndexView` is inherited from `ListView`.

If you look at docs of [List View](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) you can see that there is no method named `get_object()`. As in the docs,

> The List View render some list of objects, set by `self.model` or `self.queryset`.
>   `self.queryset` can actually be any iterable of items, not just a queryset.

So, the `self.object` you refer to in the view, doesn't exist.

But in the case of [Detail View](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview), if you look at the docs,

> The DetailView render a "detail" view of an object.
>
> By default this is a model instance looked up from `self.queryset`, but the
>   view will support display of *any* object by overriding `self.get_object()`.

The logic which you are implementing in your `IndexView` is clearly wrong.
You would need to look into the docs first.